# download image files through django

Tags: python, django, image

I am trying to download images from media folder when a user clicks on some download image button

```
from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper
import mimetypes
import settings
import os

@login_required
def download_image(request, product_id):
    # current_site = get_current_site(request)
    product_image =  Product.objects.get(object_id=product_id)
    product_image_url = product_image.product_image_url()
    print product_image_url,">>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
    wrapper = FileWrapper(open(product_image_url, 'rb'))
    print wrapper,">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
    content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(product_image_url)[0]
    response = HttpResponse(wrapper, mimetype=content_type)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % product_image_url
    return response
```

From the above view i can able to get the image path, but getting the following error

/media/product/product4959e24a4edf4f8d8afa8c529f3afaff/codes/image_dr_130.png >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Envs/comp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/user/Envs/comp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 25, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/name/cpmp/comp/projsite/apps/website/views.py", line 963, in download_image
    wrapper = FileWrapper(open(product_image_url, 'rb'))
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/product/product4959e24a4edf4f8d8afa8c529f3afaff/codes/image_dr_130.png'
```

so i am getting the correct image path,and when i entered the image path like `localhost:8000/media/product/product4959e24a4edf4f8d8afa8c529f3afaff/codes/image_dr_130.png` i am able to see the image in browser, so why am i getting the above error ?

**Update**

**settings.py**

```
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

def ABS_PATH(*args):
    return os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, *args)

# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ABS_PATH('media')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that your media is in `/media` folder, that means link `localhost:8000/<path>` do not refer to file `<path>` in your file system. However, you try to access your filename via url.

Judging from the fact that Django succesfully delivers the url, and as I guess you're using `django.core.context_processors.media` context processor to deliver your media, you can try to prepend `MEDIA_ROOT` to relative path to url, removing `MEDIAL_URL` part from it.

That is, if your settings are

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/path/to/django/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

you should find your file located at `/path/to/django/media/product/product4959e24a4edf4f8d8afa8c529f3afaff/codes/image_dr_130.png`

Comment: use `ABS_PATH(product_image.product_image_url())`

Comment: is there any way to implement the print functionality ?, because side to Download Image button, i had 'Print Image' button, so how to can we do this fucntionality, like we should take the user to print screen(ctrl+P) with only image there

Comment: sorry, but can't see how your answer differs/extends mine. as for your  new question, ask it in a new thread, it is hard to understand what you want, and comments to an answer to unrelated quesiton are not the best place to dive in details

Answer (score 1):

Solved in the below manner

```
@login_required
def download_image(request, product_id):
    # current_site = get_current_site(request)
    product_image =  Product.objects.get(object_id=product_id)
    product_image_url = product_image.product_image_url()
    wrapper = FileWrapper(open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+ product_image_url[6:], 'rb'))
    content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(product_image_url)[0]
    response = HttpResponse(wrapper, mimetype=content_type)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % product_image_url
    return response
```