# DJANGO download object has no attribute 'product_image_url'

Tags: python, django

I have I big database with images and i want to use download in my site where the user to can download personal images.

i will try to use download method from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020821/download-image-files-through-django)(without sure if that is correct) is the fist time to try using download method in my site.

but I take this error message :

```
AttributeError at /download/125/
'MyModel' object has no attribute 'product_image_url'
```

here my code :

models.py :

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    slug_name = models.SlugField()
    upload = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

views.py:

```
def download_image(request, id):
    descripts=MyModel.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    product_image =get_object_or_404(descripts,pk=id)
    print product_image
    product_image_url = product_image.product_image_url()
    image_url = MyModel.objects.get(descripts,pk=id).image_code_url()
    print product_image_url
    wrapper = FileWrapper(open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+ product_image_url[6:], 'rb'))
    print wrapper
    content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(product_image_url)[0]
    response = HttpResponse(wrapper, mimetype=content_type)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % product_image_url
    return response
```

urls.py :

```
url(r'^download/(?P<id>\d+)/$',views.download_image, name='download_image'),
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=(
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static','static_dirs'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static','static_root')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static','media')
MEDIA_URL = ('/media/')
```

html :

```
for data in images %}
<a href="{% url 'download_image' data.id %}" class="btn btn-default">Download</a>
{% endfor %}
```

any idea to help me ?

and if the image can be in .zip file I appreciate more.

Comment: What are the following printing?
`product_image =get_object_or_404(descripts,pk=id)
    print product_image`

Comment: @deaspo image name like 'name.png' after crashed `product_image_url = product_image.product_image_url()
AttributeError: 'MyModel' object has no attribute 'product_image_url'
name.png
[07/Oct/2017 00:05:36] "GET /download/126/ HTTP/1.1" 500 74676`

Comment: Shouldn't you be getting the object with the image and not the image name? Am asking this because you should be getting the model object that contains the image and then query it to return the image url, as at now you are getting the image and trying to get `.upload_code_url()`. 

`product_image = MyModel.objects.get(PK=id)`
Something like that, then you can query for `.upload_code_url()`

Comment: @deaspo I take the ome error

Comment: Alternatively call the specific db column name `.upload_image_url()
` and not `.product_image_url()`. AM not sure, probably `.image_url()`

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @deaspo I replace     `product_image=MyModel.objects.get(pk=id)
    #product_image =get_object_or_404(descripts,pk=id)
    product_image_url = product_image.upload_image_url()` and now o take this error 'MyModel' object has no attribute 'upload_image_url' any idea ?thx to help me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156134/discussion-between-chris-papas-and-deaspo).